Custom tcolorbox: add an option on the fly
Suppose I define the below tcolor box mybox. How do I, if at all possible, add an option for a specific mybox, like, say, adding the option of righthand width=3cm, like adding an option to a generic tcolorbox, like adding [colback=green] in the second example. (I am not talking about the options I may define in the definition preamble.)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    enhanced,
    skin=bicolor,
    colframe=red,
    sidebyside,
    colbacklower=white,
    % righthand width=3cm,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
    Test box.
\end{mybox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green]
    Another test box.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}


Define mybox with an optional argument that passes keys to the underlying tcolorbox.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    skin=bicolor,
    colframe=red,
    sidebyside,
    colbacklower=white,
    #1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
    Test box.
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[righthand width=3cm]
    Test box.
\end{mybox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green]
    Another test box.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}



Ah! My mistake was I thought this kind of definition preamble was limited to passing 1 extra option.
